# Borders, cell alingment and Wrap text with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to format copied cells to all borders, cell align top and cell align left, as well as wrap text.

For borders I tried

```
With rng.Borders
  .LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Current Macro:

```
Sub Copy_Data()
    Dim Src As Worksheet, Dst As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, r As Range
    Dim CopyRange As Range

    Set Src = Sheets("Template")
    Set Dst = Sheets("Report")

    LastRow = Src.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").Row

    For Each r In Src.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        If r.Value = "Planning" Or r.Value = "On Hold" Or r.Value = "Planning" Or r.Value = "Gathering Info" Or r.Value = "" Then
            If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRange = r.EntireRow
            Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, r.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
        CopyRange.Copy Dst.Range("A3")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: use the macro recorder, start it, do all the things you stated, stop it and then look at the module.

Answer (score 0):

If you record a macro you will get something like this

```
Range("A1:C10").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```

The above code can be also be written as. Notice how we use the loop to create the borders. Check what is the value of `xlEdgeLeft, xlEdgeTop, xlEdgeBottom.. etc`. You will then understand how we use the loop.

```
Dim rng As Range

'~~> Change this to whatever range you want
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:B10")

With rng
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone

    For k = 7 To 12
        With .Borders(k)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next
End With
```

Similarly for wrap text and cell alignment, simply record a macro and edit the code to suit your need :)

Comment: Sid, since you are setting the borders from 7 to 12, do you actually have to put the `slDiagonalDown` and `slDiagonalUp` to `xlNone`?

Comment: @GMalc: Yes, It is required to remove any diagonal borders if they are already present. The value of `xlDiagonalDown` and `xlDiagonalUp` are 5 and 6 respectively :)